# Any way to capture partial screenshot with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing an app for Android and i have this issue - after i have taken a picture with the camera, i need to crop it. But the coordinates for the rectangle i have dragged over the capturing area start from the screen's 0,0 coordinates aka touch coordinates do not match actual picture's - if i try to crop the image with these using PIL, i get a partial result.
One possible solution would be to take a partial screenshot with these coordinates and get the cropped picture that way.
I tried to use pyscreenshot, but then i found out that it does not work on Android.
Any ideas how to capture a partial screenshot on Kivy?

Thank you

Comment: There is a method `screenshot` in the class `WindowBase`. Also, every widget in kivy has another method `export_to_png` to save the widget and all of its children as an image in png format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For possible anyone with the same issue - i did not find any good way to grab a screenshot and crop selected portion out of it. I did, however, solve it this way - i move to a new screen, resize picture to device's screen resolution and from then i can crop it with touch without no issues - i did not have to find a clever way to map screen coordinates with image's. After cropping and saving i resize the image back to a fixed resolution. This is not a elegant solution, but still will serve my purpose.
Thank you anyone who thought along with me.